# Condensing Multiple Columns That Are in a Yes/No Format to One Descriptive Column

Tags: r

This problem has plagued me for quite some time.  I always just work around it with a for loop, but I think it's finally time for me to find a quicker and more elegant way of doing this.

As an example, let's say I have a data frame containing information on whether an item is red or blue.  The information is presented in this way:

```
item.df <- data.frame(Item=seq(1,5), Red=c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N"), Blue=c("N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N"))
```

Clearly, this is not the most condensed way to represent this information.  Instead of having two separate Red and Blue columns, I simply want one item color column that would contain "Red", "Blue", or "Neither" (Or NA would also be acceptable).

Obviously, I can achieve this by creating an empty Item.Color column and then filling it in by looping through each individual row.  But I'm sure there is a quicker way to do this.

Back when I was a true R novice, I tried to do it by:

```
item.df$Item.Color <- if(item.df$Red=="Y"){"Red"}
```

but I quickly learned this doesn't work, because the if statement will only read the first element in item.df$Red.

Could there be a way to achieve this using do.call() or one of the apply() functions?  I've attempted, but I could never get it to do quite what I wanted.  Thanks in advance for any insight you might be able to provide!

p.s. I would also be grateful to hear any suggestions for a better title for this question.  For me, that always seems to be the hardest part in asking questions.

Comment: Your example is not far off.  Have a look at the `ifelse` function, which allows applying an if condition over a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the trick, it even checks if the data contains rows where both `Red` and `Blue` are TRUE (`== "Y"`).

```
item.df[["condensed"]] <- NA
item.df = within(item.df, {
  if(any(Red == "Y" & Blue == "Y")) stop("Blue and red cannot both be TRUE")
  condensed[Red == "Y"] <- "Red"
  condensed[Blue == "Y"] <- "Blue"
})
```

The trick here is that the same syntax for taking a subset can be used for assignment:

```
# Getting a subset from a vector
A[B > 2]
# Or assigning NA to that subset 
A[B > 2] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks, probably creating the `condensed` column can also be done inside the `within`. This can also be done using the `mutate` function from `plyr` I believe.

Comment: I agree. Very interesting. I will definitely start making more use of such a neat little function.

Answer (score 2):

I like [@Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033808/paul-hiemstra) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12898190/1270695), but you can also do this pretty easily by pasting combinations together and factoring. When assigning the labels to your factors, remember that the levels are alphabetic by default (thus, `c("NN", "NY", "YN", "YY")`):

```
item.df <- data.frame(Item=seq(1, 6), 
                      Red=c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y"), 
                      Blue=c("N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y"))

item.df$Item.Color <- factor(paste0(item.df$Red, item.df$Blue),
                             labels = c("Neither", "Blue", "Red", "Both"))
item.df
#   Item Red Blue Item.Color
# 1    1   Y    N        Red
# 2    2   Y    N        Red
# 3    3   N    Y       Blue
# 4    4   N    Y       Blue
# 5    5   N    N    Neither
# 6    6   Y    Y       Both
```